# Calculate the limit of an integral

Tags: calculus-and-analysis

How can I use *Mathematica* to find the  limit:$$\lim_{x\rightarrow 0^{+}}\frac{\int_{1}^{+\infty}\frac{e^{-xy}\quad-1}{y^3}dy}{\ln(1+x)}=?$$

I tried this 
 `Limit[Integrate [(E^(-y*x) - 1)/y^3, {y, 1, \[Infinity]}]/Log[1 + x], 
 x -> 0, Direction -> 1]`, but the returned answer is`Undefined`. Any suggestions ?

Answer (score 4):

```
$Version
```

> "10.2.0 for Mac OS X x86 (64-bit) (July 7, 2015)"

The `Direction` of the limit should be -1 to approach 0+. From the documentation, "Direction -> -1 takes variables to approach their limits by decreasing from larger values."

```
Limit[Integrate[(E^(-y*x) - 1)/y^3, {y, 1, \[Infinity]}], x -> 0, 
 Direction -> -1]
```

> 0

Including the `1/Log[1+x]` factor

```
Limit[Integrate[(E^(-y*x) - 1)/y^3, {y, 1, \[Infinity]}]/Log[1 + x], 
 x -> 0, Direction -> -1]
```

> -1

Comment: Yep,according to your answer,I change `Direction -> 1`to `Direction -> -1`,it comes expected result. Thanks !

Comment: Also, `Series[int/Log[1+x], {x,0,1}]` gives `-1`.